# How to use Iframe in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, iframe

I tried to find a way to add iframe to my react native app. I found [react-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe), but it didn't work for me. I followed the documentation. I just imported react-iframe and copied the iframe tag to use.

My result is like the image below.

[image]

I need another way to use iframe in react native app. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answer on my question.

I used webview for display Iframe.

```
<WebView
   source={{html: '<iframe width="100%" height="50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}}
   style={{marginTop: 20}}
/>
```

Comment: What's the point of using iframe and webview together? That sounds unecessary. Agree with @FlorinDobre.

Comment: if we use WebView, can we go to fullscreen on Android?

Comment: @LakshanSS Yes, It's full screen like normal app, but it does not smooth like a native app.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa: to develop in `codesandbox`? community/`WebView` doesn't seem to work for `react-native-web`, or I am overlooking their `node.js` container things. All else we must go into `vs code`, `expo` [browser](https://docs.expo.io/guides/running-in-the-browser/) development strategy... I guess there is no use to not build a native app twice... wait yes there is

Answer (score 37):

Try to use `react-native-webview`:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

....

<WebView
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          bounces={false}
          javaScriptEnabled
          style={{ height: 500, width: 300 }}
          source={{
            html: `
                  <!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                    <head></head> // <--add header styles if needed
                    <body>
                      <div id="baseDiv">${iframeString}</div> //<--- add your iframe here
                    </body>
                  </html>
            `,
          }}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        />
```

You can use an `iframeString` value like:

```
<iframe src="https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/snippets/html/iframe-simple-contents.html"
            title="iframe Example 1" width="400" height="300">
</iframe>
```

**Notes:**

**1)** since `source.html` param can be any html string you could also pass the `iframeString` directly without any html page wrapper. In my cases I found it's easier to customize the displayed content with that outer html wrapper code.

**2)** known issues about iframes and rn-webview:

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues?q=iframe+is%3Aopen

**3)** Link to snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@florindobre99/webview-example

More info about webview here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

More info on resolving issues with WebView inside the ScrollView:

https://yelotofu.com/reactnative-why-your-webview-disappears-inside-scrollview-c6057c9ac6dd

Comment: I agree your answer, but it did not correct 100%. Thank

Comment: I tested my answer and it works great. https://snack.expo.io/HJFjnhVo7. You asked for a way to display iframe and I provided a working way it to you with link to documentation for you customize the response according to your needs. I do not understand why you did not accept it and added same answer with simplified parameters.

Comment: @FlorinDobre not sure if you're aware but the above link produces the following error: `Minified React error #130`

Comment: The snack link with example from my above comment was tested about 3 years ago. It might not work now, I haven’t tested it in a long time. But the webview code from my answer should still work.

Comment: @Hyetigran I updated the snack code to use the community webview: https://snack.expo.dev/@florindobre99/webview-example

Comment: curious to know if there are any advantages to using an iframe in a webview, instead of just a straight up webview?

Answer (score 3):

How about adding the iframe link directly in webview source attribute
Ex:

```
<WebView
   source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE'}}
   style={{marginTop: 20}}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers worked fine if only the `iframe` had to be displayed but for displaying `iframe` mixed in with other data I found this link to be a lot more helpful.

https://github.com/native-html/plugins/tree/master/packages/iframe-plugin#readme