# Is possible use many iframes on same view (React Native)

Tags: react-native, iframe

I use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922235/2400373

This is the code:

```
<WebView
   source={{html: '<iframe width="100%" height="50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}}
   style={{marginTop: 20}}
/>
```

this works perfectly but now I need to show in a 2 or 3 iframes view, is it possible?

Now I tried this solution:

```
<WebView
       source={{html: '<iframe width="100%" height="50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><iframe width="100%" height="50%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cqyziA30whE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'}}
       style={{marginTop: 20}}
 />
```

simply repeating the iframe to be shown 2 times but only shown once

Comment: Can't you just use a few different `WebView` s?

Comment: I tried but this is the error: "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <> ...</>

Comment: You must wrap them all in a `View` or similar.

Comment: When I use View, don't show the tag WebView just tag View and your content